# Does Unkempt Harold count as grenade damage?

Tags: borderlands-2

Some abilities boost grenade damage, and some damage from attacks-that-aren't-grenades count despite not being grenades. Does the Unkempt Harold damage count as grenade damage?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. I tested by putting a point in [Steady](http://borderlands.wikia.com/wiki/Steady).